# How to copy files and paste in folder by creating a current date in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of `Excel Workbooks` that update periodically. I want to copy these files every Sunday to the folder created with current date in the name (e.g. `Workbooks-28.06.2017`). I have written a batch script but it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
@echo OFF

xcopy /s C:\Users\rerraboina\Desktop\tracker automation\Consolidation\test dynamic

for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined mydate set mydate=%%d
md %mydate:~0,8%
```

Comment: You should enclose the paths with spaces in double quotations.

Comment: @Azeem thank you, it is creating only folder with the date but it is not copying the files from source folder to the date folder. Please help

Comment: You are welcome! You have to accept the edit to show it. BTW, you are `xcopy`ing before creating the folder and the second parameter `destination` is missing e.g. `xcopy source destination`. I've posted my answer. You can go through it and then compare it with yours to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

**archive.bat**

```
@ ECHO OFF

PUSHD %~dp0

FOR /f "skip=1" %%d IN ('WMIC OS get LocalDateTime') DO IF NOT DEFINED myDate SET myDate=%%d
SET archiveDirName=Workbooks-%myDate:~0,8%
MD %archiveDirName%

XCOPY /S /I /Y "Excel Workbooks" %archiveDirName%\

POPD
```

`"Excel Workbooks"` is an example folder which contains multiple subfolders having on `*.xlsx` file in each.

Comment: It created only folder as "Workbooks-2017062" but files are not transferred. I have tried with and without replacing "Excel Workbooks" with my path, but its not working.

Comment: @AayushmanR: Actually, that was an example. I've used `Excel Workbooks` in my code. You have to put the folder name with full path in quotations. If that doesn't work, then post your code here with error.

Comment: @ ECHO OFF

     FOR /f "skip=1" %%d IN ('WMIC OS get LocalDateTime') DO IF NOT   DEFINED mydate set mydate=%%d md %mydate:~0,8%
SET archiveDirName="Workbooks-%myDate:~0,8%"
MD %archiveDirName%

    XCOPY /s "C:\Users\rerraboina\Desktop\tracker automation\Production Launches Cosolidation 2 june" %archiveDirName%

Comment: I have posted the code in the above comment. The only error is that it is creating the folder with current date but the files are transferring from source path to the created date fodler.

Comment: @AayushmanR: Yes. It copies the files from all the sources to the newly created folder. Do you want to copy each file along with its own folder?

Comment: it worked, thank you. The only problem I figured out was that it is not copying files if the destination folder is in the source folder. I think this would do, appreciate it.

Comment: @AayushmanR: You are welcome! :) BTW, you can set the destination path. It's your choice. You can prefix the `archiveDirName` with your destination folder path and it'll make copies of the files to that folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147792/discussion-between-aayushmanr-and-azeem).